# Simultaneous Use in freeRadius 3.0

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, freeradius

I install Ubuntu server 22.04

I install apache2

I install PHP

I install PostgreSQL and phpPgAdmin

I install freeradius 3.0

ln -s /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/sql /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql

ln -s /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/rest /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/rest

ln -s /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/sqlcounter /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sqlcounter

nano /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/default

and un-comment all sql lines

I did same thing in /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/inner-tunnel

I use /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/postgresql/schema.sql
to create sql database in postgresql

I edit /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/sql
to link freeradius to postgresql

I create user in radcheck table with password. use wpa2-enterprise in my engenius wifi device. It works perfect.

My goal now is to limit to specific user or group of users to only one login simultanous. If a second pc or phone try to login, it have to reject.

I try many manipulation I found in forum but nothing works. I probably did mistake somewhere but I don't know where.

I tried : [How to fixe the number of concurrent logins per user in freeradius 3.0?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1061197/how-to-fixe-the-number-of-concurrent-logins-per-user-in-freeradius-3-0)

and tried : https://www.vpsserver.com/community/tutorials/10/setup-and-configuration-of-freeradius-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04-64bit/

Not working for me. But I use postgresql and not mysql, I don't know if it make difference. Firt user can connect, but the second device that use the same username and password can connect too, and I configure Simultaneous-Use := 1.

If you neef more information, ask me.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks for help

Richard